# How to match specific strings together from two lists?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script

I'm trying to match specific individual strings together. For example, I'd like the following to be paired:

file1 and 123.jpg
file2 and 432.jpg
file3 and 345.jpg

Currently, I'm using the following inefficient method that matches all possibilities between the two lists:

```
declare -a name1=("file1" "file2" "file3")

declare -a name2=("123.jpg" "432.jpg" "345.jpg")

for y in "${name1[@]}"
do
  for x in "${name2[@]}"
  do
    echo $y$x
  done
done
```

This script provides the following output:
file1123.jpg
file1432.jpg
file1345.jpg
file2123.jpg
file2432.jpg
file2345.jpg
file3123.jpg
file3432.jpg
file3345.jpg

How can I have only the desired pairs matched so that the output looks like the following: file1123.jpg file2432.jpg file3345.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Indexed arrays are… indexed. :) Each element has an index (number). You want to pair 0th element of `name1` with 0th element of `name2`, 1st with 1st etc.

Instead of looping over elements you need to loop over indices. `${#name1[@]}` expands to the length of the array named `name1`. Let's denote this length *N*. If *N* is greater than *0* then indices are from *0* to *N-1*. The following snippet loops over the indices of `name1`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a name1=("file1" "file2" "file3")
declare -a name2=("123.jpg" "432.jpg" "345.jpg")

for (( i=0; i<"${#name1[@]}"; i++ ))
do
    printf '%s\n' "${name1[i]}${name2[i]}"
done
```

Notes:

- [`printf` is better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618).
- [variables should be double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618) unless you really know you don't want them quoted.
- The code loops over the indices of `name1`. If `name2` is shorter then any missing element will expand to an empty string. If `name2` is longer then excessive elements will not be retrieved.